# How to keep phone powered down while charging with ClockworkMod Touch Recovery?

Tags: charging, clockworkmod-recovery, power-on

In the course of setting up CyanogenMod 7.2 on my T-Mobile G2 (also known as the HTC Desire Z), I installed ClockworkMod Touch Recovery. My usual practice before that was to power off my phone and plug it in to a USB cable, attached to a wall socket, for recharging. However, with ClockworkMod Touch, trying to do this results in the phone always booting to the recovery mode, whether I plug in the cable before or after shutting off the phone.

This is a nuisance; in effect, I have to leave my phone powered on at all times, and turn off the sound when I'm sleeping. I suppose I could just leave it at the Recovery menu, but leaving the phone at a menu where two accidental touches to the screen could wipe the phone seems like a bad idea.

If I recall correctly, I initially had an earlier version of ClockworkMod Recovery installed, which had a menu option for powering off the phone. I only had that version installed briefly.

Comment: Just leave your phone up&running while charging. There's no technical reason to power it down. Charging time will be (almost) identical if you switch off the display. PS: The charging screen is also shown by a running system (while the device is powered on).

Comment: I don't like having the phone advertise that I am available to communicate when I am not, along with a long list of other features of the phone that aren't really useful or meaningful when I am sleeping. I could disable things piecemeal, but it seems like it would be simpler to just shut the phone off when I am asleep.

Comment: When you see that charging screen, Android is running in a special charging mode which is not too different from Airplane mode. So just keep your phone powered and switch to airplane mode atomatically: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alfray.timeriffic

Answer (score 1):

You are stuck with this. This is the way ClockworkMod Recovery works. I did a search and the devs on xda say if you dont like it unroot your phone.

It is indeed a nuisance since powered off chargin charges faster. Though, oh well!

Comment: You're not stuck with this. Most phones show some special 'charging screen' however this is also a full running system consuming power too. If the modder takes the extra time to also implememt this, it'll work too with mods.

Comment: @Passingby, can you provide a link to that comment by the devs?

Answer (score -1):

Put your phone into airplane mode before going to sleep.

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem described - the OP is asking for a method to keep his device completely powered down while charging. Airplane mode is an entirely separate function.

Comment: To be fair, the OP stated he wants the powered down because that is simpler than "disabling things piecemeal", and airplane mode would appear to be the best of both worlds.